# Apache with proxy and ssl not listening on port 80

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, ssl, https, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running apache 2.4.29 in ubuntu 18.04 and I have the following setup in 000-default.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_ssl.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_ssl.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On

    SSLCertificateKeyFile /pathtokey/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /pathtokey/chain.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /pathtokey/fullchain.pem

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/


    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Apache is working as a proxy to a tomcat server, both with SSL. If I use the url with https, apache works well, but when I try to use http I cannot get redirected to https. I checked and it seems that apache does not listen or handles connections from port 80 (I checked with telnet also)

If I remove SSL settings, and keep one virtualhost in port 80, I can work with no SSL, that works fine in port 80, but when I enabled ssl only I can use the server with https

Is there any way to use http and be redirected to https?

Comment: Update: I make a telnet from the local console using the domain the web server responds, but from outside not. The thing is that when I remove SSL port 80 is working, and I checked ufw and iptables and are ok

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem: I had a routing in IPTABLES that send the traffic from port 80 to 8080

Comment: Are you saying you found the problem and this was it? If so, please make that more clear. Right now it sounds like you're trying to add information to your question, which you should do by using the EDIT button under your question.